# Actions on Google simulator "Failed to unlink account" error

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm currently developing an action for Google Assistant using the Actions on Google simulator.
The action uses Google Sign-in to retrieve the users email. To test my flow for users who don't have have their account linked I would unlink using the unlink button in the profile section in the simulator

Today I tried to do this, but the console is giving me an error that unlinking was unsuccessful.

[image]

Sadly, this is the only information that I am getting. Refreshing the page and re-enabling testing on my project did not resolve this issue. Does anyone know what might be causing this or have an alternative way to unlink my account from my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue of not being able to unlink my account in the simulator has resolved it self after a few days without any changes on my own side. So it might have been an issue on Google's side. The answer posted by Saif was a good work around while this issue wasn't solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question correctly what you are asking. Correct me if am wrong your are asking about how to unlink the linked account with actions on google and for that you are phasing the problem right ??
for that may be **https://myaccount.google.com/permissions** this link would help to unlink the account which you have linked . Hope this solves the problem if not then please elaborate again the problem so i can understand properly .

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the permission overview allowed me to remove my linked account. Although this helped me unlink my account for now, I am still get the error when I try to unlink my account through the simulator after re-linking my Google account again. So for now I will have to use the permission page to do any unlinking.

Comment: great... @Jordi

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why there may be an issue with the console, but the [Google Account Linking page](https://myaccount.google.com/accountlinking) contains a list of every account you've linked.

Comment: Thanks for the link, sadly I cannot see my account for this action on the page you provided. It did show linked accounts for other actions that are also in development.